# TypeScript: Function as object key

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

For sane reasons, I need to have an object that has functions as key in an object, e.g:

```
function a() {}
function b() {}

const obj = {
  [a]: b
}
```

The reason for this is that I want to map the values of function `a` to function `b` and be able to remember and remove mappings again.

Now I wonder how to write typings for this in TypeScript. If I do

```
type MapFunctions = { [key: Function]: Function };
```

I will get the error

> ```
> An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.ts(1023)
> ```

But how would I write a type for this?

Comment: Those reasons are not sane and what you're trying is impossible.

Comment: Agreeing with @ritaj, if you look into what index type you have for your property `[a]`, it's being converted to a string and doesn't remain a `Function`: `console.log(typeof Object.keys(obj)[0] === 'string');`. Your approach does not work in Javascript, and giving it a type declaration does not change that.

Comment: @ritaj first of all it is definitely possible, try this in your browser: `const a = () => {}; 
const obj = {[a]: "val"}; 
console.log(obj[a]); ` second of all, can you elaborate on why you believe this is not sane?

Comment: @fjc thank you for your insight, I did not know the functions will bne stringified!

Comment: that is typescript question... the question is how to typescript follow the signature  of `a` & `b` functions when they updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `object` can't take a function reference as the key, but you can use a `Map` which can take a function as a key

```
function a() {}
function b() {}

const map = new Map<() => void, () => void>();

map.set(a, b);

map.get(a)();
```

Comment: that is typescript question... the question is how to typescript follow the signature of a & b functions when they updated